# Get highest number from each row of a triangle and sum it up

Tags: c#

I have below triangle of numbers which will be sent as parameter to a `function`

```
5
9 6
4 6 8
0 7 1 5
```

Now this will be received as string in below function with the format `5#9#6#4#6#8#0#7#1#5`. So far I've tried to ripple only the digits from `#`

```
public class Sample
{
    public static string validtrianglesum(string input)
    {
        string sum="0";
        foreach(char num in input)
        {
            if(!num.Equals('#'))
            {
                Console.PrintLine(num); //here am getting only the nums excluding #
                //How to sum up based on each row
            }
        }
        return sum; //return 
    }
}
```

how could highest number from each row and sum them and how could I identify the rows to sum it up? Hope to find some help.

Comment: But how do you think your program figures how many number exist on each line? Is it always starts with `1` and increments?

Comment: @SonerGönül Each line will contain only one extra number for sure and as of now I need output for only above 4 lines..

Comment: 1) You know that the 1st row has length 1, the 2nd row has length 2, etc. That's how you can identify them. 2) You cannot sum `string`s, so you need to convert them to `int`s.

Comment: is your input fixed, or did you choose this?

Comment: 2nd part am clear.. But stuck on first Part @Dennis_E

Comment: I chose this.. @lordkain

Comment: so, you can change it to something else, say 5,9#6,4#6#8  now you have a row seperator and an item seprator

Comment: Once I receive the string in function, I can change it to any format inside method but while receiving as parameter it should come as is..

Comment: Let me get this clear... Do you want to get the largest number from each row, then sum up all of these numbers?

Comment: Exactly @DarrenGourley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to determine the size of the triangle. By *size* I mean the height/width. E.g, the provided triangle has a size of 4.

If the size is `n` then the number of elements in the triangle will be `n(n + 1)/2`. When the number of elements in the input is known this can be solved to determine `n` (the size) by solving a second degree polynomial and picking the positive solution (the expression below involving a square root):

```
var triangle = "5#9#6#4#6#8#0#7#1#5";
var values = triangle.Split('#').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
var sizeAsDouble = (-1 + Math.Sqrt(1 + 8*values.Count))/2;
var size = (Int32) sizeAsDouble;
if (sizeAsDouble != size)
  throw new ArgumentException("Input data is not a triangle.");
```

So with the provided input `size` will be `4`. You can then use the size to select each row in the triangle and perform the desired arithmetic:

```
var maxValues = Enumerable
  .Range(0, size)
  .Select(i => new { Start = i*(i + 1)/2, Count = i + 1 })
  .Select(x => values.Skip(x.Start).Take(x.Count))
  .Select(v => v.Max());
```

The first `Select` will compute the necessary indices to correctly slice the array of values which is done in the second `Select`. Again the formula `n(n + 1)/2` is used. If you want to you can merge some of these `Select` operations but I think spliting them up makes it clearer what is going on.

The output of this will be the numbers `5, 9, 8, 7`. If you want to sum these you can do it like this:

```
return maxValues.Sum();
```

Comment: Perfect @Martin Liversage and its awesome explanation too.. Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Summing up all values in each row:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> Sum(string input)
{
    int i = 0, s = 0, z = 1;
    foreach (var v in input.Split('#').Select(int.Parse))
    {
        s += v;
        if (++i != z) continue;
        z++;
        yield return s;
        s = i = 0;
    }
}
```

The same in one line:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> Sum(string input) => new Func<int, int, IEnumerable<int>>((i, z) => input.Split('#').Select(int.Parse).GroupBy(e => i++ == z && (i = 1) != null ? ++z : z, e => e).Select(e => e.Sum()))(0, 1);
```

Summing up all the highest values in each row:

```
private static int Sum(string input)
{
    int i = 0, s = 0, z = 1, m = 0;
    foreach (var v in input.Split('#').Select(int.Parse))
    {
        if (v > m) m = v;
        if (++i != z) continue;
        z++;
        s += m;
        i = m = 0;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Same in one line:

```
private static int Sum(string input) => new Func<int, int, int>((i, z) => input.Split('#').Select(int.Parse).GroupBy(e => i++ == z && (i = 1) != null ? ++z : z, e => e).Select(e => e.Max()).Sum())(0, 1);
```

I am returning the sums as `IEnumerable<int>` and with the `yield return`. If you just want to print out the answers change the return type to `void` and remove the `yield return s;` line.

Comment: good one, but change parameter name so everyone will see what this does and is maintainable. and see latest coment :)

Comment: Can you please let me know in the same signature I've write now?

Comment: CodeFreek you should be able to debug and change it right :)

Comment: I tried your code but it sums up all the numbers in each row, But yea row wise calculation its working fine.. I need to fetch max number from each row and sum it up..

Comment: @lordkain.. trying on it.. :)

Comment: @CodeFreek Do you want the sum of each row or the sum of the highest values in each row?

Comment: fetch highest value from each row and sum it up is my requirement.. :)

Comment: @CodeFreek Added that

Answer (score 3):

Let's break this down as follows:

Firstly, turn the input into an array of numbers:

```
string input = "5#9#6#4#6#8#0#7#1#5";
var numbers = input.Split('#').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Now let's assume we have a `MakeTriangular(int[])` method that turns an array of numbers into a sequence of rows with the first row being of length 1, the second of length 2 and so on, so that it returns `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>`.

Then we can use that along with Linq to calculate the sum of the maximum value in each row as follows:

```
int sum = MakeTriangular(numbers).Sum(row => row.Max());
```

Which gives the answer.

The implementation of `MakeTriangular()` could look like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> MakeTriangular(int[] numbers)
{
    for (int i = 0, len = 1; i < numbers.Length; i += len, ++len)
        yield return new ArraySegment<int>(numbers, i, len);
}
```

Putting it all together into a compilable Console app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string input = "5#9#6#4#6#8#0#7#1#5";
            var numbers = input.Split('#').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
            int sum = MakeTriangular(numbers).Sum(row => row.Max());
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> MakeTriangular(int[] numbers)
        {
            for (int i = 0, len = 1; i < numbers.Length; i += len, ++len)
                yield return new ArraySegment<int>(numbers, i, len);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Matthew for the beautiful explanation. But I do not have enough reputation to upvote.. Once I get I will comeback and do it.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ:

```
string input = "5#9#6#4#6#8#0#7#1#5";
var nums = input.Split('#').Select(s => Int32.Parse(s));

var res = Enumerable.Range(0, nums.Count())
                    .Select(n => nums.Skip(Enumerable.Range(0, n).Sum()).Take(n));
                    .Where(x => x.Any());  // here you have IEnumerable<int> for every row 
                    .Select(arr => arr.Max());
```

Answer (score 1):

Please give credit to Widi :) but this is your request

```
var rows = Sum("5#9#6#4#6#8#0#7#1#5");
var total = rows.Sum();

private static IEnumerable<int> Sum(string inp)
{
    int i = 0, s = 0, z = 1;
    foreach (var v in inp.Split('#').Select(int.Parse))
    {
        s = Math.Max(s, v);
        if (++i == z)
        {
            z++;
            yield return s;
            s = i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But if you see my comments on @Widi's answer this will sum up each row and not the max number on each row.. I need to identify max number of each row and sum it up..

Answer (score 0):

I would use 2 functions:

1st one to convert the string into a tree representation:

```
  List<List<int>> GetTree(string data)
    {
        List<List<int>> CompleteTree = new List<List<int>>();
        List<int> ValuesInLine = new List<int>();

        int partsinrow = 1;
        int counter = 0;

        foreach (string part in data.Split('#'))
        {
            int value = int.Parse(part);
            ValuesInLine.Add(value);

            if (++counter == partsinrow)
            {
                CompleteTree.Add(ValuesInLine);
                ValuesInLine = new List<int>();
                counter = 0;
                partsinrow++;
            }
        }

        return CompleteTree;
    }
```

2nd one to sum up the maximum of the lines:

```
    int GetSumOfTree(List<List<int>> tree)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        foreach (List<int> line in tree)
        {
            line.Sort();
            int max = line[line.Count - 1];
            sum += max;
        }

        return sum;
    }
```